# Ito diffusion coefficient matrix and covariance

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, covariance

An Ito diffusion process can be written as $$dX_t = \mu(X_t, t)dt + \sigma(X_t, t)dB_t$$ where $\mu$ is the drift term, $\sigma$ is the diffusion term, and $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Suppose $X_t$ is two-dimensional, $X_t = (X^1_{t}, X^2_{t})$. I know the drift term is simply the componentwise mean, $\mu(X_t,t) = (\mu^1_{t}, \mu^2_{t})$. What about the diffusion coefficient?

Edit: I see that $\sigma$ is the square root of the covariance matrix. I'm trying to find the covariance matrix, and did this calculation, denoting $\mu_x = \mu(X_t, t)$ and $\mu_y = \mu(Y_t,t)$):
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[(dX_t - \mu(X_t))(dY_t - \mu(Y_t))] &= \mathbb{E}[dX_t dY_t] - \mu_y \mathbb{E}[dX_t] + \mu_x \mathbb{E}[dY_t] - \mu_x \mu_y\\
    &= \mathbb{E}[dX_t dY_t] - \mu_x\mu_y
\end{align*}

(The second equality is due to $\mathbb{E}[dX_t] = \mu_xdt$, $\mathbb{E}[dY_t] = \mu_ydt$ so that the middle two terms cancel)

From here, though, how does one compute $\mathbb{E}[ dX_y dY_t]$?

Comment: The covariance matrix for the infinitesimal increments is $(\sigma \sigma^T) dt$.

Comment: @Ian I'm confused -- I defined $\sigma$ to be the infinitesimal covariance matrix itself.

Comment: No, $\sigma$ is not a covariance, though it is related to the covariance. Think of the 1D case: it is like a standard deviation, not like a variance.

Comment: @Ian Hm. So $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ would be the analogous "$\sigma$'s" for each of the 1D processes right? So are the formulas I wrote correct?

Comment: $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in your second formula are variances. In the first one they're like standard deviations. Otherwise yes that's correct.

Comment: Why are they behaving differently in the two formulas? The only difference between the two matrices is that the first one has 0 correlation between $X_t^1$ and $X_t^2$ and the second has some correlation

Comment: Because of what you were writing down in the first place. You said the first one was $\sigma$ while the second one is the covariance matrix.

Comment: @Ian ah I understand! (I think) -- so once the covariance matrix is found, then the $\sigma$ in the SDE is the square root of the covariance matrix. But then how does one find the covariance matrix? Would you have to explicitly compute the integral $\int_0^t (X_s^1 - \mu_s^1 )(X_s^2 - \mu_s^2) p(X_1,X_2,s)ds$? Seems like a lot, especially if the process $X_1,X_2$ is quite simple.

Comment: You can get the infinitesimal covariance matrix from $\sigma$ if $\sigma$ is given, it is $\sigma \sigma^T$. The actual covariance of the components of the process at time $t$ requires an integral, though. (For some intuition for why, think about the 1D case where the variance is the integral of $\sigma^2$. If you didn't already know that, look up the Ito isometry.)

Comment: Right... but I am looking for $\sigma$ in the first place. I don't know the infinitesimal covariance either. All I have is a high-level description of a process I want to model. I know the drift. How would you derive $\sigma$ from there?

Comment: .It sounds like you may want to give us an idea about this high level description so we can help you with your actual question. Because ultimately, from the math point of view, you need to be given either $\sigma$ or the infinitesimal covariance matrix in order to obtain the other one.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's true. I posted the question here, if you could take a look I would appreciate it a lot! I think it is interesting, myself. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039662/covariance-of-two-specific-ito-processes