# Covariance of two specific Ito processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance

So I have two 1D diffusion processes,
$$dX_t = \mu_X dt + b_X dB_t$$
$$dY_t = \mu_Ydt + b_Y dB_t.$$

I want to write these as a 2D process $Z_t = (X_t, Y_t)$.

Now, the dynamics are piecewise in the sense that only one of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ occurs at one time, and the choice depends on a function $f(X_t,Y_t)$.

Specifically if $f>0$, then $X_t$ is occurring with probability $1-\epsilon$, and $Y_t$ is occurring with probability $\epsilon$. If $f<0$ then $Y_t$ occurs with probability $1-\epsilon$ and $X_t$ occurs with probability $\epsilon$.

When each is occurring, it is very simple: $X_t$  ($Y_t$) has constant drift $p_x$ ($p_y$) and both have variance $1$.

So I defined

\begin{equation}
    \mu_X = \begin{cases}
    (1-\epsilon)p_x &\text{ if } f<0\\
    \epsilon p_x &\text{ if }f>0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    b_X = \begin{cases}
    (1 -\epsilon) &\text{ if } f<0\\
    \epsilon &\text{ if }f>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The process $Y$ is defined similarly:
\begin{equation}
    \mu_Y = \begin{cases}
    \epsilon p_y &\text{ if } f<0\\
    (1-\epsilon)p_y &\text{ if }f>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    b_Y= \begin{cases}
    \epsilon &\text{ if } f<0\\
    (1-\epsilon) &\text{ if }f>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

To get these, I assumed that when a process is occurring with probability $1-\epsilon$, then you can simply scale the full (i.e. occur with probability 1) transition density $\mathcal{N}(\mu t, \sigma^2 t)$ to $\mathcal{N}(\mu t (1-\epsilon), \sigma^2 t(1-\epsilon))$. If this is wrong, please correct me.

Now, I'm not sure what the covariance structure is other than the fact that only one of the two processes occurs at a time.

My guess was to simply combine these into the 2D case with no correlation, but it doesn't seem right.
\begin{equation}
b_Z = 
    \begin{cases}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    (1-\epsilon)&0\\
    0&\epsilon
    \end{pmatrix} &\text{ if } f<0\\
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \epsilon&0\\
    0&(1-\epsilon)
    \end{pmatrix} &\text{ if } f>0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Should the off-diagonals be negative? Since the two processes are mutually exclusive, my (not very strong) intuition is that it should either be 0 or negative.

Comment: Do you check "whether a process is moving" continuously, or is there some kind of coin flip at the crossover time?

Comment: By crossover time, do you mean when $X_t$ stops and $Y_t$ begins with probability $\epsilon$ or $1-\epsilon$? Or when $f$ changes sign? I have only thought about the former probabilistically. The latter I thought about viewing as a BM hitting time.

Comment: Well, first question I guess, is $f$ continuous, and if so what is meant to happen if it becomes zero?

Comment: $f$ is a linear function of $X,Y$. For now, we can reduce it to the line $Y=X$.

Comment: When it becomes zero, then the process switches instantaneously from being $X$-dominant to $Y$-dominant or vice versa.

Comment: You can't be sure that there is a sign change that will be maintained on any neighborhood of the zero of $f$ (as you probably know the zero set of a BM is a perfect set, and the same tends to be true of diffusion processes with some nondegeneracy assumptions). So this "instantaneous switch" is in general not well defined.

Comment: Very interesting, I'm not too familiar but thank you for pointing that out. What is the consequence? (Nonuniqueness of solutions perhaps?)

Comment: So I see that a BM visits $0$ infinitely many times in the time interval $(0, \epsilon)$. But if there is a positive drift, this isn't true, right?

Comment: It still is; on a short enough time interval (depending on the relative magnitude of the coefficients), only the diffusion is "active".

Comment: Hmm I see. But there's not much to do about that, is there? And how does this have to do with the covariance of $Z_t$?

Comment: Well, since this is all a modeling problem, it depends what you really want to have happen. Do you actually want these discrete events where $X$ and $Y$ turn on and off? If so then you will probably want to restart the process at a point where $f$ is nonzero so that there is a finite amount of time before the next restart event occurs. If you don't need that, then I would just suggest regularizing your expressions for the coefficients so that they cross over rapidly but continuously when $f$ passes through zero.

Comment: (Cont.) Or maybe have the coefficients be driven by their own noise as well as $X$ and $Y$, to simulate the "coin flip". Alternatively there might be a way to leverage machinery along the lines of the running maximum of BM in some way, but intuitively I don't think this helps your situation.

Comment: Great points, thanks so much. I think for my purposes it would work to simply restart the process when the diffusion leaves a neighborhood of 0 (doesn't really matter what happens near 0)